# Эффект прозрачности без прозрачности

Tags: html, css, svg

Вот что бывает, когда сайт рисуют дизайнеры не из веба:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нижняя часть создана не через прозрачность, а методом умножения. Может ли в данном случае помочь SVG? Потому что у меня получается нечто темное или блеклое, ибо прозрачностью такой эффект выделения темных областей сделать не получится:

```css
.item {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  align-self: center;
}
.item .img {
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.item .img img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.item .test {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  filter: grayscale(1);
}
.item .content {
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.item .content .up {
  width: 100%;
}
.item .content .down {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #4f7bbf;
  background-position: -1000px bottom;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.item .content .down::before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(46, 85, 153, 0.7);
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -100%;
  z-index: 2;
}
.item .content .down::after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: inherit;
  background-position: left bottom;
  background-size: cover;
  filter: grayscale(1);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
 <div class="img">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kF9S.jpg" alt="" />
 </div>
 <div class="content">
  <div class="up">text text text</div>
  <div class="down" style="background-image:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kF9S.jpg');">
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Собственно вопрос: можно ли это сделать с помощью CSS, SVG, танцев с бубном?

Answer (score 2):

Используйте для наложения `mix-blend-mode: multiply;`. Правда, поддержка старых браузеров отсутствует.

```css
.item {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  align-self: center;
}

.item .img {
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.item .img img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.item .test {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  filter: grayscale(1);
}

.item .content {
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item .content .up {
  width: 100%;
}

.item .content .down {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #4f7bbf;
  background-position: -1000px bottom;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  /* Оно самое */
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}

.item .content .down::before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(46, 85, 153, 0.7);
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.item .content .down::after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: inherit;
  background-position: left bottom;
  background-size: cover;
  filter: grayscale(1);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kF9S.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="up">text text text</div>
    <div class="down" style="background-image:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kF9S.jpg');">
      text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
      text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
      text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
      text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Источник](https://css-tricks.com/basics-css-blend-modes/)

Comment: В вашем примере куда-то пропал эффект от `grayscale()`